# Vue not applying styles when inserting with v-for directive

Tags: css, vue.js

I'm using a paid template, and I'm trying to apply it to the project (it's working, but not good to the eye)

This is the code

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_demo_mars" id="checkbox_demo_4" data-md-icheck checked />
<label for="checkbox_demo_4" class="inline-label">Outside vue</label>
<div id="vm_settings">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_demo_mars" id="checkbox_demo_4" data-md-icheck checked />
    <label for="checkbox_demo_4" class="inline-label">Inside VM</label>

    <template v-if="1">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_demo_mars" id="checkbox_demo_4" data-md-icheck checked />
        <label for="checkbox_demo_4" class="inline-label">Inside if</label>
    </template>

    <template v-for="setting in settings">
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_demo_mars" id="checkbox_demo_4" data-md-icheck checked />
            <label for="checkbox_demo_4" class="inline-label">Inside for</label>
        </div>
    </template>

    <button v-on:click="saveSettings">Save</button>
</div>
```

This is how it is outputed to the browser [checkbox not having the styles it should](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hI44x.jpg)

Any way to fix it?

Comment: Can you add your CSS code?

Comment: its this http://icheck.fronteed.com/ plugin probably

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Customized checkboxes are not merely styled with CSS, they are proxied: the real checkbox widget is hidden and other elements are inserted and styled in their place.

As such, there must be some call that examines the HTML and does the widget replacement. You need that to happen to each element that gets inserted. You do that by writing a [wrapper component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/select2.html). Typically, in its `mounted` hook, you would apply the initialization of the widget to `this.$el` (or something inside it).

Comment: The template has `altair_md.init()` and I'll use it on the updated() hook... it works at least